# selenium webdriver locate the element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i try to use selenium webdriver to locate a element:
[i want click the "用户查询"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG8om.png)

corresponding html:
[the red frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzg2t.png)

python:

```
>>> driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='container']/h1[2]/a").click()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='container']/h1[2]/a").click()
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.7.236900,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86)
```

how to locate this element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below xpath with indexing.

Here. [1] indicates index number of your `a` tag. suppose in your html, there are numbers of a tag available with different names like this. `用户查询`. Suppose, This text `用户查询` index number is one inside your html then use below xpath.

```
//h1[1]/a
```

If This text `用户查询` index number is two inside your `html` then use below xpath.

```
 //h1[2]/a
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely.i try it,and change into "driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='用户查询']")" none of them are working.any choice?

Comment: Your text `用户查询` is getting change when we see `html` from the browser. I have update my ans as well. Suppose your text `用户查询` is located inside html with `n(numbers)` then use xpath as `//h1[n]/a`

Comment: yes,i have try it.you are absolutely right after the website upload and switch to a frame.thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could try locating the element [based on it's link text](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text):

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("用户查询").click();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.i try it,but error no such element.i think your are right,this element is a href with text,but none of them are work,any ideas?

Comment: Could you share the HTML of the whole page please? Maybe the `<a>` tag is inside an `<iframe>` or something that would make it more difficult to locate the element?

Comment: i am very sorry to reply you lately,my vpn was broken that i can't see this web.is my fault i forget to mention it has two iframe.the sulotion is driver.switch_to_frame("xx")